# EnableOAuth2Sso Annotation Missing On Upgrade To Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

When upgrading to spring boot 2.0.0 from an earlier version, it appears that the @EnableOAuth2Sso annotation from the `spring-boot-autoconfigure` library has been removed. The migration guide and release notes are unclear as to what to use instead, or where it might have moved.

Comment: That makes sense, I apologize for not finding those originally - I will look at them and see if both are still not marked as duplicate and answer there. Thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After discussions in [an existing GitHub issue on spring boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11032#issuecomment-372100443), I was eventually led to the annotation's location in the 2.0.0 release. It has been moved to a project completely new to the 2.0.0 release artifacts.

To resolve this issue and migrate your project, add the artifact [org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth.boot/spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure) to your dependency management configuration.

Comment: Before it's suggested, I could not clarify this or otherwise provide this answer in the original GitHub discussion location, as a project maintainer chose to lock the conversation immediately after answering the question

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I was struggling from 2 days..

Comment: Thanks It worked :-)

Comment: That worked for me as well, thanks